# How to integrate SUMO vehicles into Python using TracI?

Tags: python, sumo

I am trying to simulate the charging of electric vehicles by a mobile charger, based on the charging urgency of the vehicles (EDF and Baseline are the two algorithms which determine the urgency of the charge requester vehicles). I am unable to integrate the vehicles from SUMO into my Python code. I am not understanding how to do it. The code so far looks like this:

```
'''
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import optparse
import random
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import operator  # get max value of a dict
import math  # sqrt()
from datetime import datetime
from sumolib import checkBinary
import traci
import random
import sys
from sumolib import net  # get junction's nearby edge
from helper.prior import *
from helper.helperFuncs import *

# Log System:
# Choose keywords from following to customize the log printing.
# {"core"}
# comments = {}
comments = {"core"}

# we need to import python modules from the $SUMO_HOME/tools directory
if 'SUMO_HOME' in os.environ:
    tools = os.path.join(os.environ['SUMO_HOME'], 'tools')
    sys.path.append(tools)

    dayuanSUMOpath = os.path.join("/usr", "local", "Cellar", "sumo", "1.14.1", "share", "sumo", "tools")
    sys.path.append(dayuanSUMOpath)
    print("PATH:", sys.path)
else:
    sys.exit("please declare environment variable 'SUMO_HOME'")

netfile = 'netfiles/jawad.grid.net.xml'
net_xml = net.readNet(netfile)


def run():
    if "core" in comments:
        print("\nexecute the TraCI control loop.\n")
    step = 0

    # Prepare variables used for all cycles
    # get all TLs
    # allTLIds = traci.trafficlight.getIDList() # all traffic lights id
    allTLIds = AllTLIDs  # AllTLIDs from prior
    # AllEdgeIDs from prior
    if "core" in comments:
        print("\n\nProgram starts. \n\nThere are", len(allTLIds), "traffic lights totally.\n")  # =12

    # while traci.simulation.getTime() < 200:  # unit is second. Set a short time for testing
    while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0:  # run until all v have arrived
        traci.simulationStep()  # forward one step
        if "core" in comments:
            print("\n\nCurrent step: ", step, "\n\n")

        allVehIDs = []

        # iterate each edge
        for edge_id in AllEdgeIDs:
            allVehIDs_inThisEdge = traci.edge.getLastStepVehicleIDs(edge_id)
            print(edge_id, allVehIDs_inThisEdge)

            allVehIDs.extend(allVehIDs_inThisEdge)

        print("All veh id in current SUMO step: ", allVehIDs)

        # Create/update Vehicle objects using SUMO API calls
        vehicles = [Vehicle(veh_id) for veh_id in allVehIDs]
        for vehicle in vehicles:
            vehicle.update_parameters()
            print("veh id: ", vehicle.veh_id, " Speed: ", vehicle.speed)
            print("veh id: ", vehicle.veh_id, " Neighbors: ", vehicle.neighbors)
            print("veh id: ", vehicle.veh_id, " ElectricityConsumption: ", vehicle.electricity_consumption)
            print("veh id: ", vehicle.veh_id, " Distance from starting point: ", vehicle.distance_from_start)
            print("veh id: ", vehicle.veh_id, " Position: ", vehicle.position)
            print("veh id: ", vehicle.veh_id, " RoadID: ", vehicle.road_id)
            print("veh id: ", vehicle.veh_id, " Route: ", vehicle.route)


# Class to represent a Vehicle
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, veh_id):
        self.veh_id = veh_id
        self.speed = 0
        self.neighbors = []
        self.electricity_consumption = 0
        self.distance_from_start = 0
        self.position = (0, 0)
        self.road_id = ""
        self.route = []

    def update_parameters(self):
        self.speed = traci.vehicle.getSpeed(self.veh_id)
        self.neighbors = traci.vehicle.getNeighbors(self.veh_id, 10)
        self.electricity_consumption = traci.vehicle.getElectricityConsumption(self.veh_id)
        self.distance_from_start = traci.vehicle.getDistance(self.veh_id)
        self.position = traci.vehicle.getPosition(self.veh_id)
        self.road_id = traci.vehicle.getRoadID(self.veh_id)
        self.route = traci.vehicle.getRoute(self.veh_id)


# Class to represent a Drone
class Drone:
    def __init__(self, lat, lon, speed, soc):
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
        self.speed = speed
        self.soc = soc

    def calculate_distance(self, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
        # Radius of the Earth in kilometers
        earth_radius = 6371

        # Convert coordinates to radians
        lat1_rad = math.radians(lat1)
        lon1_rad = math.radians(lon1)
        lat2_rad = math.radians(lat2)
        lon2_rad = math.radians(lon2)

        # Haversine formula
        dlat = lat2_rad - lat1_rad
        dlon = lon2_rad - lon1_rad
        a = math.sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + math.cos(lat1_rad) * math.cos(lat2_rad) * math.sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))

        # Distance in kilometers
        distance = earth_radius * c

        return distance

    def calculate_rdv_loc(self, vehicle, charging_range):
        # Calculate the speed of the vehicle based on its state of charge
        vehicle_speed = vehicle.speed / 10

        # Calculate the distance between the vehicle and the drone
        distance_vehicle_drone = self.calculate_distance(vehicle.position[0], vehicle.position[1], self.lat, self.lon)

        # Calculate the time for the drone to reach the vehicle
        time_to_reach = distance_vehicle_drone / self.speed

        # Calculate the distance the vehicle will travel during the drone's travel time
        distance_vehicle_travel = time_to_reach * vehicle_speed

        # Calculate the RDV-LOC based on the selected vehicle and charging range
        rdvloc_lat = vehicle.position[0] + (distance_vehicle_travel / 111)  # 1 degree of latitude is approximately 111 kilometers
        rdvloc_lon = vehicle.position[1]

        return rdvloc_lat, rdvloc_lon

    def charge(self, vehicle_index, rdv_loc):
        # Perform charging logic here
        pass


# Class to represent the Baseline algorithm
class Baseline:
    def __init__(self, drone, charging_range, charging_stations):
        self.drone = drone
        self.charging_range = charging_range
        self.charging_stations = charging_stations

    def charge(self, vehicles):
        # Logic for the Baseline algorithm
        pass


# Class to represent the EDF algorithm
class EDF:
    def __init__(self, drone, charging_range):
        self.drone = drone
        self.charging_range = charging_range

    def charge(self, vehicles):
        # Logic for the EDF algorithm
        pass


# Connect to SUMO and start the simulation
traci.close()
sumoBinary = checkBinary('sumo')
traci.start([sumoBinary, "-c",
             "C:/Users/Sadi M Jawad Ahsan/OneDrive - UMBC/UMBC Studies/Spring_2024/EV_charging_project/sookyoung_paper/code/jawad.grid.sumocfg"])
traci.simulationStep()

# Retrieve the IDs of the vehicles generated by SUMO
all_vehicle_ids = traci.vehicle.getIDList()

# Create/update Vehicle objects using SUMO API calls
vehicles = [Vehicle(vehicle_id) for vehicle_id in all_vehicle_ids]

# Run the simulation loop
run()

# Disconnect from SUMO
traci.close()
sys.stdout.flush()
'''
```